# Piston pushing mesh to make it rotate

Tags: animation, rigging

[image]
I need to make the piston rod push the selected mesh into a rotation around its origin. My problem or issue is that I don't know how to place the armature correctly and how the piston rod stays in contact with the mesh when it's rotating. I could really use some help with this.

Comment: hello could you make a drawing of position A and position B? Maybe you could use a Transformation constraint?

Comment: Usually it would be easier to have the rotation drive the piston (look-at).. is that acceptable?

Comment: is this what you want? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLule.gif

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As ususal there are a lot of possibilities how you can rig something. I don't claim that my solution is the easiest or most elegant, but it works:

[image]

**root node:**

no parent, can just rotate on x axis, which is pointing to the viewers eye

[image]

**big cylinder:**

has track to IK, parent is root

[image]
[image]

[image]

**Stretchy**

has no parent, copy loc from big cylinder and stretch to ik

[image]

[image]

**small cylinder**:

parent is stretchy, damped track to root

[image]

[image]

**IK**

parent is bone, has IK

[image]

**bone**

has no parent

**controller**

has no parent

result:

[image]

parent your cylinders according to their names.