# Problem with piston pushing mesh to make it rotate

Tags: animation, rigging

I've got a problem with [the solution to my previous question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/302594/piston-pushing-mesh-to-make-it-rotate), can anyone figure out what is wrong with what i've done here:
[image]

PS: I will try to comment on your answers, if you need some more information to solve my problem.
File: [image]

Comment: if my answer helped you, please click on the checkmark left of my answer. thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you nearly had it....just parent the MESH to IK

1. in object mode, select the MESH and clear parent-> keep transform
2. shift select the armature
3. go to pose mode -> select IK

[image]

ctrl-p -> Bone

result:

[image]